# How to find all texts that contains under same Class using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have to find all elements that contains same class name in HTML tag.

For Example :

Let the xpath expression `//*[@class='abc']` shows 10 elements. I need to find all text elements under same xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *List* of all the *text containing elements* those also contains same `classname` i.e. **`abc`** using either of the following solutions:

- *Python* example:

  - Using `css_selector`:

    ```
    all_text_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".abc")
    for myTextElement in all_text_elements:
        print(myTextElement.text)
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    all_text_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'abc')]")
    for myTextElement in all_text_elements:
        print(myTextElement.text)
    ```